# STRING_AGG group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a sql query which returns this:

| id | LS_NoSerie | DO_Tiers | rn | totalMatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | I607 | 1 | 80 |
| 2 | A | I3446 | 2 | 80 |
| 3 | A | I3446 | 3 | 80 |
| 4 | B | I3446 | 1 | 60 |
| 5 | B | A4123 | 2 | 60 |
| 6 | B | B7856 | 3 | 60 |

Note that here we have:

- 2 differents `LS_NoSerie` `A` and `B`
- the column `rn` corresponds to the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) of `LS_NoSerie`

I want to execute a query on a top of this result to get this:

| id | LS_NoSerie | DO_Tiers | rn | totalMatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | I607,I3446,I3446 | 1 | 80 |
| 4 | B | I3446,A4123,B7856 | 1 | 60 |

Basically I want all lines where `rn` = 1 and `DO_Tiers` get the aggregate string of the corresponding `LS_NoSerie`.

Something like:

```sql
SELECT cte.id, cte.LS_NoSerie, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(cte.DO_Tiers, ''), ','), cte.rn, cte.totalMatch
FROM (
         SELECT * FROM my_table_name
     ) as cte
WHERE cte.rn = 1
GROUP BY cte.LS_NoSerie
```

But it doesn't work as `cte.id`, `cte.LS_NoSerie`, `cte.rn`, `cte.totalMatch` are not aggregate nor part of the `GROUP BY`.

If you want to reproduce:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table_name
(
    id         INT,
    LS_NoSerie VARCHAR(255),
    DO_Tiers   VARCHAR(255),
    rn         INT,
    totalMatch INT
);

INSERT INTO my_table_name (id, LS_NoSerie, DO_Tiers, rn, totalMatch)
VALUES (1, N'A', N'I607', 1, 80);

INSERT INTO my_table_name (id, LS_NoSerie, DO_Tiers, rn, totalMatch)
VALUES (2, N'A', N'I3446', 2, 80);

INSERT INTO my_table_name (id, LS_NoSerie, DO_Tiers, rn, totalMatch)
VALUES (3, N'A', N'I3446', 3, 80);

INSERT INTO my_table_name (id, LS_NoSerie, DO_Tiers, rn, totalMatch)
VALUES (4, N'B', N'I3446', 1, 60);

INSERT INTO my_table_name (id, LS_NoSerie, DO_Tiers, rn, totalMatch)
VALUES (5, N'B', N'A4123', 2, 60);

INSERT INTO my_table_name (id, LS_NoSerie, DO_Tiers, rn, totalMatch)
VALUES (6, N'B', N'B7856', 3, 60);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the values from the rn=1 row in each group:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN id END) AS id, 
  ls_noserie,
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(do_tiers, ''), ',') AS tiers,
  1 AS rn, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN totalmatch END) AS totalmatch
FROM my_table_name
GROUP BY ls_noserie
ORDER BY ls_noserie;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/-XMD6EDg

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your sample data just some simple aggregation should get you there:

```
select
  Min(Id),
  LS_NoSerie, 
  String_Agg(DO_Tiers, ',') DO_tiers, 
  Min(rn) rn,
  Min(totalMatch) totalMatch
from t
group by LS_NoSerie;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        min( cte.Id) as Id
        , cte.LS_NoSerie as LS_NoSerie
        , STRING_AGG(CONCAT(cte.DO_Tiers, ''), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cte.Id)   as DO_Tiers
        ,1 rn
        ,Max(cte.totalMatch) as totalMatch 
FROM my_table_name cte
GROUP BY cte.LS_NoSerie
order by id
```